# multiplication table of 1-4

Tags: c++

i tried to write a code that shows the multiplication table of 1-4 but in the first attempt(below) it gave me:
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
4 0

but then sb told me to write it like this and it worked.
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
4 8 12 16

**Now my question is what was the problem with the 1st one?????

1st version:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
main(){
    int x[4][4];    
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
       for(int j=1;j<5;j++){
           x[i][j]=i*j; 
           cout<<x[i][j]<<" ";    
       }
       cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

2nd:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
main(){
    int x[4][4];    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
           x[i][j]=(i + 1)*(j + 1); 
           cout<<x[i][j]<<" ";    
       }
       cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, and not as a single line, so that it's readable.

Comment: Simply, array indices in C++ are 0 based. That is, an array of 4 elements has indices from 0-3. The first example uses indices 1-4 and thus results in Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the starting index.

Arrays begin at 0 position, so you must initialize your i and j from 0.

Otherwise, you could declare your x matrix as [5][5], and you can use i and j starting from 1.

Cheers!!

Comment: could you please explain why the 4th row of the 1st coloumn printed number 4 while j couldn't get 4? and also why the 1st three rows of the 4th coloumn printed the results of multiplication while (i) couldn't get number 4?

Comment: @prsgls Your array indices i,j for `x[i][j]` can both range only from [0, 3]. In your code, you were even accessing `x[4][4]` which is _outside_ of the actual array bounds and you ended up getting junk values while printing them.

Comment: @Zoso yes but how come that for 3 rows x[i][4] (4, 8, 12) the answers were true while it could only take up to 3? thanks for the edit btw, i just started using the website so i didnt know how to seperate the lines without enter<3

Comment: @prsgls `x[4][4]` that means you have allocated space for 16 integers consecutively (0 - 15 indexes), with the first row's 4 elements being the first 4 elements, then the second row's 4 elements being the next 4...`x[1][4]` that actually means writing to the `1*4 + 4` i.e 8th element which is still within the bounds of your 16 elements. Same with `x[2][4]` which is 12th (2 * 4 + 4). `x[3][4]` is the 16th element which is actually now beyond your initial allocation. Accessing anything beyond is just undefined behavior.